# передача параметров между контроллерами ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день.
В проекте ASP.MVC столкнулся с поведением, которое смог обойти, но не могу объяснить.
Суть вопроса: форма в представлении отправляет в контроллер массив из двух `string`. Метод контроллера должен пробросить этот массив в другой контроллер, где его есть кому обработать. И пробросить массив я не смог  - вместо массива 
 в параметры второго контроллера приходит только имя типа.
Вопрос почему так происходит? Это нормальное поведение или я сто-то сделал не так?

Код (сначала - работающая версия):
Представление (валидаторы выкинул, но следы от них остались в параметрах):

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home",  FormMethod.Post,  new { novalidate = "", name = "InputForm", ng_controller = "SubmitCtrl", role = "form" }))
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Введите адрес сайта в поле ввода и нажмите кнопку")
            @Html.TextBox(
                "Url0",
                null,
                new { type = "url", @class = "form-control", required = "", placeholder = "Enter url here", id = "url11", ng_model = "url1" })

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Выберите количество запросов к странице сайта")
                @Html.DropDownList("Url0", new SelectList(new string[] { "4", "5", "6", "7" }), new {  @class = "form-control"})
            </div>


        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="Press()" ng-disabled="InputForm.$invalid">Отправить</button>
        <div ng-show="pressed">
            <img src="~/Content/Image/please_wait.gif" />
        </div>

    }
```

Контроллер, принимающий данные из представления и пробрасывающий их в другой контроллер  (лишние блоки удалены).

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(string [] Url0)
    {
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", new {url= Url0[0], attempts=Url0[1]});

    }
```

Контроллер, обрабатывающий данные:

```
public ActionResult Index(string url, string attempts)
        {
               manager = new VMManager();
               int att;
               if (Int32.TryParse(attempts, out att)) manager.AttemptsQuantiy = att;
               manager.VM = (SiteVM)manager.ParseUrl(url);
                if (manager.VM.PageResults.Count == 0) return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", null);
                else return RedirectToAction("ShowResult", "Tool", null);
}
```

Нерабочий код:

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] url)
```

в методе `Submit` :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", new {url= Url0});
```

или

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", url= new string [] {Url0[0],Url0[1]});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение, т.к. нельзя отправлять сложные объекты при редиректе.
Когда ты делаешь редирект, ты отправляешь запрос типа GET на свой метод.
А соответственно при отправке GET запроса необходимо отправить всю информацию в качестве параметров строки запроса. И это работает только с простыми скалярными свойствами.